# foreach variable copies the value and not the reference?

Tags: apex

```
List<String> fieldsToIgnoreLowerCase = new List<String>{'crosidtmp__c', 'MasterDetail'};

for (String fieldToIgnore : fieldsToIgnoreLowerCase){
    fieldToIgnore = fieldToIgnore.toLowerCase();
}
System.debug(fieldsToIgnoreLowerCase);
```

Why doesn't this result in elements in fieldsToIgnoreLowerCase being actually set to lower case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are updating just the local varuable in the loop, because strings are immutable and they need new referance to the heap memory instead of updating them.
Java stuff.

Try something like that in the loop and it should be fine.

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < fieldsToIgnoreLowerCase.size(); i++) {
    fieldsToIgnoreLowerCase[i] = fieldsToIgnoreLowerCase[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: I see, it was weird for me coming from C# where String is a reference type, thank you!